# iPhone: Send in-app email without prompting for mailcomposer to show up?

Tags: iphone, email

I have no problem sending emails from within my app.

Right now it requires:

- User presses an email button.
- *presentModalViewController* brings up the email view (with pre-defined To:, Subject:, and Body:)
- User presses "Send"
- Email is sent.
- *dismissModalViewController* removes email view.

Can I somehow make it:

- User presses an email button.
- Email is sent.

?

Thank you in advance,

Eugene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is an important issue, and it is this way for security reasons. If this was not the necessary method, you could use an app to send massive spam from every installed device!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following link to send mail using SMTP

http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

This will work fine for google account.
You have to just simple changes in the code and works well.